Running bash scripts against a K8S Manifest file which uses Helm templating
I want to run a kubesec scan against some of my K8S manifest files, the issue is that I'm using Helm templating in my files and when I try to execute a simple bash script I get errors like these
Performing kubesec scan - Static security analysis for Kubernetes manifests
Scan result: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.backendDeploymentName":interface {}(nil)}

My bash script looks like this to run a scan against the manifest files and check the resulting scores.
#!/bin/bash

scan_result=$(curl -sSX POST --data-binary @"backend_manifest_file" https://v2.kubesec.io/scan)
scan_message=$(curl -sSX POST --data-binary @"backend_manifest_file" https://v2.kubesec.io/scan | jq .[0].message -r )
scan_score=$(curl -sSX POST --data-binary @"backend_manifest_file" https://v2.kubesec.io/scan | jq .[0].score )

echo "Performing kubesec scan - Static security analysis for Kubernetes manifests"
echo "Scan result: $scan_result"
echo "Scan message: $scan_message"
echo "Scan score: $scan_score"

if [[ "${scan_score}" -ge 5 ]]; then
    echo "Score is $scan_score"
    echo "Kubesec Scan $scan_message"
else
    echo "Score is $scan_score, which is less than or equal to 5."
    echo "Scanning Kubernetes Resource has Failed"
    exit 1;
fi;


My manifest files use Helm templating where I reference variables in my values.yaml file.
What's a solution for this?
